# Short story with cave on moon and married couple

Tags: story-identification, short-stories

I need to identify a short story - I have a feeling it is mid-20th century.

A man and wife journey to the moon, I think as tourists. They go for a walk and find a cave, within which there is a machine that enables them to read each others thoughts, and they discover they never really understood each other but loved each other anyway.

There really isn't much science in it even though the moon is involved.

Comment: Do you have any idea where you read it?  Magazine, book-size collection, one author or anthology, etc.?  If a collection or anthology, do you recall any of the other stories it appeared with?  What language and country of publication may help, too.

Comment: I really have no idea what kind of publication I read it in. Could have been a magazine or anthology. Almost certainly an SF publication rather than mixed or other genre.